# How to display parameter only by Role ID

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem when debug the code..User had been registered the field and it got to another page. But when go to the another page, all the parameter were include in URL..
example:
http://localhost:56767/Pendaftaran/VerifyEmail?Role=3&FirstName=Abu&LastName=Mutalib&ICNumber=8812511469&Gender=1&Email=abu%40gmail.com&Password=aaabbb&ConfirmPassword=aaabbb&State=16&MobileNumber=012-7415511

This is using stored procedured database on sql server.

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult AddParticipant(RegistrationModel obj)
    {
        try
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                if (this.IsCaptchaValid("Captcha is not valid")) //Added Captcha 17 May 2019 -Aidil-
                {


                    if (obj.Role == 2) //Add if else for club 17 May 2019 -Aidil-
                    {
                        if (obj.CLubRegistration != null) 
                        {

                            //Add Stored Procedured -Aidil- 15 May 2019
                            connection();
                            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("uspRegisterParticipant", con);
                            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Role", obj.Role);
                            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClubReg", obj.CLubRegistration); //Added ClubRegistration 16 May 2019 -Aidil-
                            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", obj.FirstName);
                            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", obj.LastName);
                            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ICNumber", obj.ICNumber);
                            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", obj.Gender);
                            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", obj.Email);
                            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", obj.Password);
                            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", obj.State);
                            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MobileNumber", obj.MobileNumber);  //Added MobileNumber 16 May 2019 -Aidil-
                            con.Open();
                            int i = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            con.Close();

                            //End Added Stored Procedured -Aidil- 15 May 2019

                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        connection();
                        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("uspRegisterParticipant", con);
                        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Role", obj.Role);
                        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", obj.FirstName);
                        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", obj.LastName);
                        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ICNumber", obj.ICNumber);
                        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", obj.Gender);
                        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", obj.Email);
                        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", obj.Password);
                        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", obj.State);
                        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MobileNumber", obj.MobileNumber);  //Added MobileNumber 16 May 2019 -Aidil-
                        con.Open();
                        int i = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        con.Close();
                        //End Added Stored Procedured -Aidil- 15 May 2019
                    }

                    return RedirectToAction("VerifyEmail", obj); //Update RedirectAction 27 May 2019 -Aidil-

                }
                ViewBag.ErrMessage = "Error: captcha is not valid.";
                //return View();

            }


            return View(); 


        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", e);
            return View();
        }

    }



    // GET: Pendaftaran/VerifyEmail
    //Added VerifyEmail 27 May 2019 -Aidil-
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult VerifyEmail(EmailVerificationModel obj)
    {
        try
        {

            //Add Stored Procedured -Aidil- 27 May 2019
            connection();
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("uspDisplayNameForVerification", con);
            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", obj.FirstName); //Added called from AddParicipant 28 May 2019 -Aidil-
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", obj.LastName); //Added called from AddParicipant 28 May 2019 -Aidil-

            con.Open();
            //int i = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
            con.Close();
            return View(obj); //Update view () to view(obj) -Aidil- 29 May 2019

        }

       catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", e);
            return View();
        }
    }
    //End Added VerifyEmail 27 May 2019 -Aidil-

}
```

Supposedly i want show only this :
http://localhost:56767/Pendaftaran/VerifyEmail?Role=3

not like this one:
http://localhost:56767/Pendaftaran/VerifyEmail?Role=3&FirstName=Abu&LastName=Mutalib&ICNumber=8812511469&Gender=1&Email=abu%40gmail.com&Password=aaabbb&ConfirmPassword=aaabbb&State=16&MobileNumber=012-7415511

Comment: What is your `EmailVerificationModel`? Anyway, not sure why you are using SPs and doing this with custom code. Why not start with [built in helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/features-api/account-confirmation-and-password-recovery-with-aspnet-identity) and work from there? I really don't see a need for SP here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the whole object while redirecting i.e obj which will tale all parameters 
you can just pass the required field

try

```
  return RedirectToAction("VerifyEmail", obj.Role);
```

this will take Role parameter as query string to next page.

Comment: Yes...of course successful.. But i want pass value First Name and Last Name to the VerifyEmail page.. example:

Hi Aidil Scaft

meaning Aidil is FirstName and Scaft is LastName

Comment: You can use anonymous object for same, like 
return RedirectToAction("VerifyEmail", new {FirstName=obj.FirstName,LastName=obj.LastName,Role=obj.Role})
Likewise other properties whatever you want